# ENSIME not finding some dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, ensime

I'm using ensime on Windows with scala 2.11.8, sbt .13.8 and ensime 1.0 with Sublime3. I can build the project with SBT or through ENSIME without an error but ensime is showing an error in my editor. I have rebuilt the .ensime file and restarted multiple time but the errors are consistent. One is an unused import for eri.commons.config.SSConfig and then when I use SSConfig.
[image]

Comment: you need to compile your project.